# Dataframe of strings writing to CSV with each column on a new line

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
effective_date         Price
"1986-01-01 12:30:45", "100"
"1990-02-02 11:15:30", "150"
```

and I wish to write this to a CSV -

```
write.table(my.data.frame,
            col.names=FALSE,
            row.names=FALSE,
            sep=",",
            "output.csv")
```

I'd expect the CSV to contain:

```
"1986-01-01 12:30:45", "100"
"1990-02-02 11:15:30", "150"
```

However, this isn't what happens. Instead, when I write to the CSV I get:

```
"1986-01-01 12:30:45"
"100"
"1990-02-02 11:15:30"
"150"
NA
```

I'm not sure what could be causing this. Can anyone help? I've tried all variations of the parameters of `write.table` and nothing seems to work.

Thank you.

EDIT: I have also tried `write.csv` and it didn't work either.

*EDIT*: once more:

It seems the line that is causing this problem is

```
df["effective_date"] <- format(strptime(df["effective_date"],
                                          "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                        "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Which I use to make sure that dates that are midnight are forced to show 00:00:00 (so I can load it properly in various spreadsheet programs).

Why does this line screw up the CSV writer?

Comment: there is `write.csv` if you want in `base` package

Comment: @joel.wilson unfortunately it doesn't work either. I will edit the post

Comment: You can use `write_csv` from `readr` which should work for most cases

Comment: `df = data.frame(effective_date = c("1986-01-01 12:30:45",  "1990-02-02 11:15:30"), Price = c(100, 105))
write.csv(df, "/pathname/sample_so.csv")` this works well!!

Comment: @joel.wilson @akrun I have added a final edit. I traced the problem code to a `format()` call, and I can't figure out why its breaking it.

Comment: The `xts` library fixes this problem, however I don't know why.

Comment: @rec could you share the `dput(my.data.frame)` of your data?